# get multiple ids with rails4-autocomplete gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I can select multiple names however I cannot get multiple ids into the id field. Is there a way to get a string or array of id's? I tried adding multiple: true and data-delimiter => ',' to the id field but that doesn't work. Thanks for any help.

[image: screen shot 2014-02-24 at 7 44 13 pm]

```
= simple_form_for :message, url: :messages do |f|
        = f.input :master_name, label: "To:", :url => autocomplete_master_name_conversations_path, :as => :autocomplete, id_element: "#master_name_id", input_html: {'data-delimiter' => ',', :multiple => true}

        = f.input :recipient_id, as: "string", input_html: {id: "master_name_id", 'data-delimiter' => ',', :multiple => true}

        = f.input :body, label: false, as: "text", placeholder: 'Write message...', :input_html => { :rows => 5 }
        = f.button :submit, 'Send', :class => "btn btn-lg btn-primary"
```

Comment: What is the difference between your To: and Recipient: fields?  Are you trying to get the list of ids you are talking about in the recipient field?

Answer (score 0):

don't put 'data-delimiter' => ',', :multiple => true inside the input_html, put it along side others